# ToolTip on DatagridView freezes application when PerMonitorV2 DPI awareness is enabled

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip, dpi

This issue can be fully recreated in the VS WinForms designer + manifest, hence why the question is devoid of any code.

The setup is as follows:

- Have two screens, main screen scaled to 100%, second to 125%
- Create a new .NET Framework 4.7.2 WinForms application
- Add a `DatagridView` and `ToolTip` from the toolbox
- Via the designer, assign some tooltip text to the `DatagridView` (calls `SetTooltip`)
- Add an application manifest that enables `PerMonitorV2` awareness:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

- Start the application on the main screen, then move it over to the secondary screen
- Hover the mouse over the `DatagridView`

The application freezes with a single CPU core fully busy. It seems to be stuck at
`System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WmShow()`, or a `DefWndProc`, fluctuating on where I "Break all" to get the call stack. Unfortunately I couldn't debug it further than this. Please find a full call stack at the end.

Further observations are:

- It does not happen if `PerMonitor` instead of `PerMonitorV2` is used.
- If the secondary screen is unplugged or even just scaled to 100% in-situ, the application immediately unfreezes.
- It seems to be independent of the targeted framework. I tested 4.5 through 4.8 and even the new .NET 5.0 template in VS.
- It works fine if other control types are used - I only found the `DatagridView` to have this issue
- It's independent of the `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` setting in app.config

My system is:

- Windows 10 Pro 21H1
- OS build 19043.1526
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Is there something that must be implemented in `PerMonitorV2` vs. `PerMonitor` that could cause this issue? Is it just a bug in the .NET Framework?

A full call stack of the main thread while it is hanging. It is fluctuating somewhat depending on where I break all. But the main parts are captured here:

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WmShow()  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 8270, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)   Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmNotify(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 78, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message})  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 275, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = -1, int pvLoopData = 0) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext})   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown
>   CrashTest.exe!CrashTest.Program.Main() Line 19  C#
```

Addendum:
On Jimi's suggestion (see comment) I experimented with cell-specific tooltips and found out that it doesn't freeze if...

- `dgv.ShowCellToolTips` is set to `false`
  or with `ShowCellToolTips = true`...
- The mouse is on a cell or header that displays a tooltip on its own e.g. via `cell.ToolTipText`

In the latter case, it still freezes when the mouse is moved to e.g. the background instead.

Demo:
[image: Crash Demo]

Comment: Did you test a .Net 5 project with `Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);` in Program.cs (with a manifest that only specifies the System compatibility)? Did you also test the executable (i.e., not running the app with Visual Studio)? -- In .Net Framework 4.8, `PerMonitorV2` should be set in `App.config`.

Comment: @Jimi The same thing happens when I set it programatically in .NET 5 with only Win10 support enabled in the manifest. I didn't mention it, but I also tried the app.config route for 4.8 - same behavior. Good points though, since manifest route is not the recommended route for newer frameworks.

Comment: All right, I'll give it a look (when possible). Did you also test the `CellToolTipTextNeeded` event, to set the `e.ToolTipText` property instead (if the DGV is bound to a DataSource)? Or setting the Cells' `ToolTipText` property. Or is it just about the ToolTip of the grid Control itself?

Comment: @Jimi Please see the edit at the end of the post. I tried it and other tooltips or turning cell tooltips off completely prevent the freezing. Added short demo video as well.

Comment: You need to be very specific about what .Net version you're testing (e.g., .Net Framework 4.8 is **very different** from .Net Framework 4.7.2) -- Also, where the DpiAwareness type is set (as mentioned, `PerMonitorV2` it should be set in `App.config` (in `<ApplicationConfigurationSection>`, not `<appSettings>`), that's how it works) -- Try to set `<runtime><AppContextSwitchOverrides value=""Switch.System.Windows.Forms.UseLegacyToolTipDisplay=false""/></runtime>` in `App.config`, [...]

Comment: [...] which also implies that all accessibility features (`Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures`, `...2` and `...3` are set to `false`. If that fails, disable everything setting all to `true`. Also what `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` is set to.

Comment: I'm aware that it is all different. Hence why I tested it in many configurations (various frameworks incl. 4.x and 5.0, enabling dpi awareness via manifest, app.config, programatically). Most combinations of the settings you mentioned - all came out to the same result -> Drag the form to second, differently scaled monitor, hover over the DGV background and it freezes.